# Mediaelement.js load() and play() issue

Tags: javascript, django, html5-video, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I'm using [mediaelementplayer](http://mediaelementjs.com/) on my site to play some video from youtube. I've written my own playlist, wherein I can click on any track in the playlist, and the player will automatically start playing that track.

Here are some relevant parts of the code:

**Initialization**:

```
var videoplayer = new MediaElementPlayer("#videoplayer",
{
defaultVideoWidth: 480,
defaultVideoHeight: 270,
videoWidth: -1,
videoHeight: -1,
audioWidth: 960,
audioHeight: 30,
startVolume: 0.8,
loop: false,
enableAutosize: true,
features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume'],
success: function(mediaElement,domObject) {
  mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
//Next song.
playTitle((currentIndex<playlist.length-1)?currentIndex+1:0);
  }, false);
},
startLanguage: '',
translations: [],
translationSelector: false,
googleApiKey: '' });
```

This is the part where I change the track from the current one to the next one:

```
function playTitle(url){
videoplayer.pause();
videoplayer.setSrc(mejs.Utility.absolutizeUrl(url));
videoplayer.load();
videoplayer.play();
}
```

Problem is, the next track does not get loaded. The present track gets paused, *and* the next track's length is displayed, but it does not start playing.

Here's the interesting part: If I type the same steps in the chrome console, it works perfectly, as intended. The current track gets paused, the next one gets loaded, and on entering `videoplayer.play();`, it starts playing.

I'm guessing it is some kind of delay issue, during which some event gets fired. I'm not able to figure out which one, and how to trap it!

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?